# Change jenkins ip address

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-cli

I have jenkins installed on vagrant and working fine.
Whenever I change my location jenkins won't start even though its status is running!
I want to know how to resolve this issue because I'm always on move and can't stay in the place where I configured jenkins for the very first  time.
thanks

I tried to see if I can change something in config file but didn't work

Comment: If you have it installed on vagrant? Shouldn't vagrant give you dns names to use?

Comment: how do I proceed to do this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution by removing the ip field in config.vm.network "public_network", ip "my ip" in the vagrant file.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).